# Installing Ruby and RubyGems

Tags: ruby

Hi everybody I would like to know is it possible to install Ruby and RubyGems in apache2. Because i have already a web using apache2 and want to install [a Fedena](http://projectfedena.org/)  which requires Ruby and RubyGems to work and would like this site to be under main site as a subdomain.

Thanks in advance for sharing comments.

Comment: This may help: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-with-rvm

Answer (score 0):

First install ruby using below command

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-full build-essential
```

So if you want to have RubyOnRails running on apache, make sure you have installed these.

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 apache2-mpm-prefork apache2-prefork-dev
```

Comment: But i already have apache2 installed which is current runing under my live web.

Comment: Then install the other two packages i.e. apache2-mpm-prefork apache2-prefork-dev

Comment: is it not going to effect apache2 which is running currently right?

Comment: No it should not. If it does you can remove the packages using

sudo apt-get purge apache2-mpm-prefork apache2-prefork-dev

Comment: Hi Vivek have you ever try to install Fedena with apache2 or lampp.

Comment: No I haven't tried Fedena but I created some webapps for apache using Ruby. I think it should work for Fedena as well. If you don't want to disturb your current environment try these things in virtual environment.
Please refer to below link to get started:

http://www.townx.org/index.php?q=ruby_on_rails_on_xampp_with_fastcgi_for_ubuntu_hoary